# hacer funciones en mysql

Tags: mysql, funciones, function

Muy buenas estimados colegas programadores, necesito una ayuda en funciones en **MySQL** tengo mi Funcion y me sales un error

> # 1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might*
>   want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

TRADUCIDO:

> # 1418 - Esta función no tiene ninguno de DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL o READS SQL DATA en su declaración y el registro binario está habilitado
>   (es posible que * quiera * usar la variable
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators menos segura)

Alguien me puede ayudar en eso por favor, alguien que tenga conocimiento, le dejo mi código para verificar cual seria el problema... aaah otra ayudita mas por favor en ves de hacerlo así de largo lo quiero hacer mas corto, verificar los caracteres si tiene MAYÚSCULA, minúscula, numero y algún carácter especial (._+-) no incluye el espacio (| |) ni el @ y el texto sea mínimo 8 caracteres entre esos caracteres debe haber uno de eso (1 MAYÚSCULA, 1 minúscula, un numero y un carácter especial) teniendo uno de eso lo demas no hay problema ejemplo (Este.mundo2019), esa función es justamente para eso pero lo hice largo por mucha emergencia

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION VerificarCaracter (_Usuario VARCHAR(50), _Pass VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN

    DECLARE CantCaracterUsu Int;
    DECLARE CantCaracterPas Int;
    DECLARE CaracterUsu Int;
    DECLARE Cont Int;

    DECLARE ContP Int;
    DECLARE ContPMAY Int;
    DECLARE ContPmin Int;
    DECLARE ContPNum Int;
    DECLARE ContPCar Int;
    DECLARE ContPEsp Int;
    DECLARE ContPArr Int;

    SET CantCaracterUsu = CHARACTER_LENGTH(_Usuario);
    SET CantCaracterPas = CHARACTER_LENGTH(_Pass);
    SET CaracterUsu = "";
    SET Cont = 0;

    SET ContP = 0;
    SET ContPMAY = 0;
    SET ContPmin = 0;
    SET ContPNum = 0;
    SET ContPCar = 0;
    SET ContPEsp = 1;
    SET ContPArr = 1;

    If CantCaracterUsu>=8 then
            If CantCaracterPas>=8 then
                    WHILE ((Cont<=CantCaracterUsu) AND (ContPmin = 0)) DO -- verifica si es minusculas
                            SET CaracterUsu = _Usuario(Cont);
                            Case CaracterUsu 
                                    When "a" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "b" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "c" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "d" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "e" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "f" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "g" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "h" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "i" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "j" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "k" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "l" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "m" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "n" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "o" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "p" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "q" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "r" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "s" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "t" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "u" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "v" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "w" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "z" then
                                            SET ContPmin = 1;
                            END CASE;
                            SET Cont = Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((Cont<=CantCaracterUsu) AND (ContPMAY = 0)) DO -- verifica si es MAYUSCULAS
                            SET CaracterUsu = _Usuario(Cont);
                            Case CaracterUsu
                                    When "A" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "B" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "C" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "D" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "E" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "F" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "G" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "H" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "I" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "J" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "K" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "L" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "M" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "N" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "O" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "P" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "Q" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "R" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "S" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "T" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "U" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "V" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "W" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "Z" then
                                            SET ContPMAY = 1;
                            END CASE;
                            SET Cont = Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((Cont<=CantCaracterUsu) AND (ContPNum = 0)) DO -- verifica si es Numero
                            SET CaracterUsu = _Usuario(Cont);
                            Case CaracterUsu
                                    When "0" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "1" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "2" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "3" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "4" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "5" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "6" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "7" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "8" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "9" then
                                            SET ContPNum = 1;
                            END CASE;
                            SET Cont = Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((Cont<=CantCaracterUsu) AND (ContPCar = 0)) DO -- verifica si es Numero
                            SET CaracterUsu = _Usuario(Cont);
                            Case CaracterUsu
                                    When "." then
                                            SET ContPCar = 1;
                                    When "_" then
                                            SET ContPCar = 1;
                                    When "-" then
                                            SET ContPCar = 1;
                                    When "+" then
                                            SET ContPCar = 1;
                            END CASE;
                            SET Cont = Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((Cont<=CantCaracterUsu) AND (ContPEsp = 1)) DO -- verifica si es Numero
                            SET CaracterUsu = _Usuario(Cont);
                            Case CaracterUsu
                                    When " " then
                                            SET ContPEsp = 0;
                            END CASE;
                            SET Cont = Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((Cont<=CantCaracterUsu) AND (ContPArr = 1)) DO -- verifica si es Numero
                            SET CaracterUsu = _Usuario(Cont);
                            Case CaracterUsu
                                    When "@" then
                                            SET ContPArr = 0;
                            END CASE;
                            SET Cont = Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;                    
            END IF;
    END IF;

    If ((ContPMay = 1) AND (ContPmin = 1) AND (ContPNum = 1) AND (ContPCar = 1) AND (ContPEsp = 1) AND (ContPArr = 1)) Then
    SET ContP = 1;
    END IF;

    RETURN ContP;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizá esto pueda ayudar:

```
    DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION VerificarCaracter (_Usuario VARCHAR(50), _Pass VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CantCaracterUsu Int;
    DECLARE @CantCaracterPas Int;
    DECLARE @CaracterUsu Int;
    DECLARE @Cont Int;

    DECLARE @ContP Int;
    DECLARE @ContPMAY Int;
    DECLARE @ContPmin Int;
    DECLARE @ContPNum Int;
    DECLARE @ContPCar Int;
    DECLARE @ContPEsp Int;
    DECLARE @ContPArr Int;

    SET @CantCaracterUsu = CHARACTER_LENGTH(_Usuario);
    SET @CantCaracterPas = CHARACTER_LENGTH(_Pass);
    SET @CaracterUsu = "";
    SET @Cont = 0;

    SET @ContP = 0;
    SET @ContPMAY = 0;
    SET @ContPmin = 0;
    SET @ContPNum = 0;
    SET @ContPCar = 0;
    SET @ContPEsp = 1;
    SET @ContPArr = 1;

    If @CantCaracterUsu>=8 then
            If @CantCaracterPas>=8 then
                    WHILE ((@Cont<=@CantCaracterUsu) AND (@ContPmin = 0)) DO -- verifica si es minusculas
                            SET @CaracterUsu = _Usuario(@Cont);
                            Case @CaracterUsu 
                                    When "a" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "b" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "c" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "d" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "e" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "f" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "g" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "h" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "i" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "j" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "k" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "l" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "m" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "n" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "o" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "p" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "q" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "r" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "s" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "t" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "u" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "v" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "w" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                                    When "z" then
                                            SET @ContPmin = 1;
                            END CASE;
                            SET @Cont = @Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET @Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((@Cont<=@CantCaracterUsu) AND (@ContPMAY = 0)) DO -- verifica si es MAYUSCULAS
                            SET @CaracterUsu = _Usuario(@Cont);
                            Case @CaracterUsu
                                    When "A" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "B" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "C" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "D" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "E" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "F" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "G" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "H" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "I" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "J" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "K" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "L" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "M" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "N" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "O" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "P" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "Q" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "R" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "S" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "T" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "U" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "V" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "W" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                                    When "Z" then
                                            SET @ContPMAY = 1;
                            END CASE;
                            SET @Cont = @Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET @Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((@Cont<=@CantCaracterUsu) AND (@ContPNum = 0)) DO -- verifica si es Numero
                            SET @CaracterUsu = _Usuario(@Cont);
                            Case @CaracterUsu
                                    When "0" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "1" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "2" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "3" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "4" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "5" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "6" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "7" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "8" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                                    When "9" then
                                            SET @ContPNum = 1;
                            END CASE;
                            SET @Cont = @Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET @Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((@Cont<=@CantCaracterUsu) AND (@ContPCar = 0)) DO -- verifica si es Numero
                            SET @CaracterUsu = _Usuario(@Cont);
                            Case @CaracterUsu
                                    When "." then
                                            SET @ContPCar = 1;
                                    When "_" then
                                            SET @ContPCar = 1;
                                    When "-" then
                                            SET @ContPCar = 1;
                                    When "+" then
                                            SET @ContPCar = 1;
                            END CASE;
                            SET @Cont = @Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET @Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((Cont<=@CantCaracterUsu) AND (@ContPEsp = 1)) DO -- verifica si es Numero
                            SET @CaracterUsu = _Usuario(@Cont);
                            Case @CaracterUsu
                                    When " " then
                                            SET @ContPEsp = 0;
                            END CASE;
                            SET @Cont = @Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;

                    SET @Cont = 0;
                    WHILE ((@Cont<=@CantCaracterUsu) AND (@ContPArr = 1)) DO -- verifica si es Numero
                            SET @CaracterUsu = _Usuario(@Cont);
                            Case @CaracterUsu
                                    When "@" then
                                            SET @ContPArr = 0;
                            END CASE;
                            SET @Cont = @Cont + 1;
                    END WHILE;                    
            END IF;
    END IF;

    If ((@ContPMay = 1) AND (@ContPmin = 1) AND (@ContPNum = 1) AND (@ContPCar = 1) AND (@ContPEsp = 1) AND (@ContPArr = 1)) Then
    SET @ContP = 1;
    END IF;

    RETURN @ContP;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Yo por ejemplo, declaro las variables en el set para reducir código pero eso ya es de cada quien.

Comment: lo hice y me sale este error...

#1064

Comment: Intenta quitando el declare y el delimiter ponlo DELIMITER $$

Comment: no funciona, no lo registra y no absolutamente nada

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS ESTIMADO